# Canadian taxes in cartThrob

Tags: cartthrob, tax

I want to apply tax rule for canadian state in cartthrob . Can anyone guide me for that? Because the states/country dropdown has US states but not canadian states.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change up your `locales` config.

> If you wish to modify the states and/or countries that are output, you can use your own custom list by renaming `system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/config/_my_locales.php` to `my_locales.php` (remove the leading underscore) and editing that file.

http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/locales_config/index.html